# facebookredirect.axd in multi tenant application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I have one facebook mvc3 application that actually consists of several facebook apps.
Every app has it's own 'virtual path' (defined in the global.asax)

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{ns}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, ns = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This means they have all use the same physical app, but have different paths: mydomain.com/facebookapp1, mydomain.com/facebookapp2, ...

The problem is that when I call for user authentication, the facebook page is called with a return url of mydomain.com/facebookredirect.axd. Facebook then decides this url is not part of that specific app, so it returns an error message.

So my question: where does the Facebook C# SDK get this facebookredirect.axd link from? I would like to change it to mydomain.com/facebookapp1/facebookredirect.axd. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to separate your applications into multiple IIs applications?

```
app1.mydomain.com
app2.mydomain.com
```

etc..

Each app has its own host header.

That way they are isolated and aren't dependent on each other in terms when you want to deploy/update changes.